# Centering markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

How might one be able to implement this:

```
map.on('popupopen', function(centerMarker) {
    var cM = map.project(centerMarker.popup._latlng);
    cM.y -= centerMarker.popup._container.clientHeight/2
    map.setView(map.unproject(cM),16, {animate: true});
});
```

but in a way that depends on a Leaflet marker being clicked (not a popup opening)?

What I am trying to do is set up my map so that when any marker on it is clicked, the map zooms in to a much closer view of the marker's location. When my markers are hovered over, they show their popups, so I cannot use 'popupopen'.

I've tried doing `layer.on('click'....` but when I do that, I get a "Cannot read property of _latlong undefined" error.

Comment: Code that doesn't work isn't a good substitute for an explanation of what that code is expected to do. Please define a proper problem statement and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the latlng passed by the click event. Create a function like this:

```
function clickZoom(e) {
     map.setView(e.layer._latlng,16, {animate: true});
}
```

and you can call it on the click event by adding `.on('click', clickZoom)` when you create the layer.

Here is an example fiddle that shows it at work:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/zpv3pj02/

Note that, in the example, you can also call the function from within onEachFeature (instead of when the layer is created), but you will need to use `e.target._latlng` instead of `e.layer._latlng`.

Comment: Thank you, @nathansnider! This is exactly what I needed for my code. Everything is working the way I want it to. :)